# CMake generated Ninja project fails at compiling with GCC

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, ninja

I have a cross platform CMake project that works perfectly with `make/gcc` on Linux and with `MSVC` on Windows. I wanted to give `ninja` a try and compare it with `make`. This is how I am creating the `ninja` project:

```
cmake -GNinja ../Source/
```

and then I run

```
ninja
```

but it fails with this error

```
/usr/bin/c++ -DmyPreprocessors ... -ImyIncludes ... -g3 -o0 -m32 -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/myProj.dir/myCode.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/myProj.dir/myCode.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myProj.dir/myCode.cpp.o -c /path/to/myCode.cpp 

cc1plus: fatal error: CMakeFiles/myProj.dir/myCode.cpp.d: No such file or directory
```

and when I check `CMakeFiles/myProj.dir/` there is no `myCode.cpp.d` file.

But when I change the compiler to `clang` everything magically works! Ninja starts compiling and then successfully links.

When I run `ninja` in verbose mode I get the exact same command except the compiler is `clang` (`/usr/bin/c++` => `/usr/bin/clang++-3.9`).

what is going on here?

**EDIT:**

Here is a sample CMakeLists.txt file that I used to reproduce the same error:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(randomProj)

set(SOURCE_FILES myFile.cpp)

include_directories(Generic)

set(EXECUTABLE "TEST")

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE} ${SOURCE_FILES})
set(LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/my/libs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -w -g3 -o0")
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE}  ${LIBRARIES})
```

and my `myFile.cpp` is this:

```
int main(){}
```

I did not specify anything explicitly for `gcc`. For `clang` however I just export the `CC` and `CXX` flags:

```
export CC=clang-3.9
export CXX=clang++-3.9
```

and then I call cmake.

Comment: [mcve] would be helpfull there. Also show, how do you set compiler to `gcc`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev added the example. This very simple example fails with `gcc` but works fine with `clang`

Comment: We found out that it is related to the `o0` flag but couldn't solve the problem but by removing it or using the `make` generator instead.

Comment: We realized that `-o` is for the compiler output file, not for the optimization level (`-O`). Without checking in depth, here a possible explanation: While the `make` generator places the two `-o` parameters so that only the second, correct one is considered, the `ninja` generator might be confused or generating wrong output dependencies upon adding `-o` manually. Anyway removing `-o0` or using `-O0` shall solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer: The [`-o`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) flag is for stating the compiler output file, which is also done by the CMake generator itself, while the [`-O`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) flag selects the optimization level. While it seems to be ignored by the make files produced by the `make` generator, this wrong flag seems to cause the `ninja` generator to produce wrong compiler commands.

Anyway removing the `-o0` flag or turning it into `-O0` solves the problem in your short example and makes the ninja version to compile also.